# misc bibliography

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

I am trying to get this in text citation to work for @misc but it doesn't seem to work, whatever I try. I have look at previous questions, but non of these help. I seriously don't know why its not working. I simply, put my url into citethisforme and get the bibtex entry however no matter what generator I use overleaf always rejects/doesn't show the citation. What am I doing wrong or does latex not support this type of citation?

[image]

```
@misc{properties: alumina - aluminium oxide - al2o3 - a refractory ceramic oxide_2021, url={https://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=52}, journal={AZoM.com}, year={2021} }


@article{abdo2019experimental,
  title={Experimental analysis on the influence and optimization of $\mu$-RUM parameters in machining alumina bioceramic},
  author={Abdo, Basem and Anwar, Saqib and El-Tamimi, Abdulaziz M and Abouel Nasr, Emad},
  journal={Materials},
  volume={12},
  number={4},
  pages={616},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{saikko1998low,
  title={Low wear and friction in alumina/alumina total hip joints: a hip simulator study},
  author={Saikko, Vesa and Pfaff, Hans-Georg},
  journal={Acta Orthopaedica Scandinavica},
  volume={69},
  number={5},
  pages={443--448},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{madfa2014use,
  title={Use of zirconia in dentistry: An overview},
  author={Madfa, Ahmed A and Al-Sanabani, Fadhel A and Al-Qudami, Nasser H and Al-Sanabani, Jabr S and Amran, Abdullah G},
  journal={The Open Biomaterials Journal},
  volume={5},
  number={1},
  year={2014}
}

@article{kaleli2018effect,
  title={Effect of different restorative crown and customized abutment materials on stress distribution in single implants and peripheral bone: A three-dimensional finite element analysis study},
  author={Kaleli, Necati and Sarac, Duygu and K{\"u}l{\"u}nk, Safak and {\"O}zt{\"u}rk, {\"O}zg{\"u}r},
  journal={The Journal of prosthetic dentistry},
  volume={119},
  number={3},
  pages={437--445},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{pasaribu2003friction,
  title={Friction reduction by adding copper oxide into alumina and zirconia ceramics},
  author={Pasaribu, HR and Sloetjes, JW and Schipper, Dirk J},
  journal={Wear},
  volume={255},
  number={1-6},
  pages={699--707},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to help you with a picture of your code only. Can you maybe copy the relevant section of your code as a minimal working example and add it to your question? That will make helping you out a lot easier for others.

Comment: Sorry, i've put my code in

Comment: I think your problem is the fact that the key you use to refer to your reference (e.g. `madfa2018effect`) cannot have spaces and I'd probably try to avoid special characters as much as possible. But in general: Yes, `@misc` is normally supported.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. It seems that the bibliography generators bibtex output is wrong perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Your `@misc` entry misses an key and titel, for example like this:

```
@misc{testkey, 
  title={properties: alumina - aluminium oxide - al2o3 - a refractory ceramic oxide_2021}, 
  url={https://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=52}, 
  journal={AZoM.com}, 
  year={2021}
}
```

Change `testkey` for your needs ...

Comment: Often accessed-date is noted in the biblio.